# LLVM's -globalopt pass does not optimize global variables

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have the following LLVM IR program:

```
@test1 = global i32 3, align 4
@test2 = common global i32 0, align 4

; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
  store i32 4, i32* @test2, align 4
  %1 = load i32* @test1, align 4
  ret i32 %1
}
```

When I use opt (version 3.3) to run with the `-globalopt` pass the bitcode stays the same. However, I would expect that `@test1` is marked as [constant](http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/docs/LangRef.html#global-variables) and `@test2` eliminated since the program only stores to `@test2`.

Do I have to run opt with some analysis passes before or why does the pass not perform as I expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [linkage section of the langref](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#linkage-types) (emphasis mine):

> `common`
>   “`common`” linkage is most similar to “`weak`” linkage, but they are used for tentative definitions in C, such as “`int X;`” at global scope. Symbols with “`common`” linkage are merged in the same way as `weak` symbols, and **they may not be deleted if unreferenced**. `common` symbols may not have an explicit section, must have a zero initializer, and may not be marked ‘`constant`‘. Functions and aliases may not have common linkage.
>   ...
>   `external`
>   If none of the above identifiers are used, the global is **externally visible**, meaning that it participates in linkage and can be used to resolve external symbol references.

So `@test1` is externally visible which means it isn't guaranteed to be a constant (can be changed from outside), and `@test2` is of a linkage type which explicitly says it may not be removed even if unreferenced.